# Etymologie "bei[m]" "i[m]" und ähnliche

Tags: etymology

Es existieren für Wörter wie "bei" und "in" Zusammenziehungen mit den nachfolgenden Artikeln, also etwa "beim" für "bei dem". Dies ist allerdings nur für Maskulina und Neutra der Fall, nicht jedoch für Feminina:

> bei*m* Mann
> bei*m* Kind
> bei *der* Frau

analog bei "in":

> i*m* Kopf
> i*m* Loch
> i*n der* Kneipe

Leider hat meine Internet-Recherche dafür nichts ergeben und auch der Kluge (Etymologisches Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache) äußert sich dazu nicht, wenn er auch "bei" aus dem Gotischen ("um - herum") herleitet und mit "ambi-" in Verbindung bringt.

Andererseits existieren für "zu" durchaus Zusammenziehungen für alle drei Genera:

> zu*m* Mann
> zu*r* Frau
> zu*m* Kind

Ich wäre für Hinweise zur Genese dieser Zusammenziehungen und insbesondere dem Grund, warum solche bei Femininae nicht existieren, dankbar.

Comment: Ich glaube, da muss man nicht so weit wie in die Ethymologie suchen, denn wie sollte eine solche Zusammenziehung denn aussehen? "**beir**"? Das ist keine besonders gängige Lautkombination im Deutschen und geht auch nicht leicht von der Zunge.

Comment: Es gibt diese Verkürzungen ja durchaus, wo sie besser klingen: *inner Kneipe*.

Comment: @Janka: in der Sprache, in der "inner" ein Wort ist, da existiert auch nur ein Artikel: "de" (und, aber ich spreche kein Norddeutsch, deshalb ist das nur eine Vermutung, auch nur ein Genus). Ich habe allerdings (und, ja, diesen wichtigen Hinweis habe ich verabsäumt zu geben) die Frage in Bezug auf die *deutsche Sprache* formuliert.

Comment: @tofro: das wäre eine durchaus mögliche Erklärung.

Comment: @bakunin *'ner* als Kurzform von *einer* ist kaum ein Dialektwort: Siehe z. B. https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/’ner https://de.pons.com/übersetzung/deutsch-englisch/%27ner Auch gibt es in den meisten (wenn nicht allen) deutschen Dialekten die drei normalen Genera, wenn auch der bestimmte Artikel vielleicht abgekürzt ist.

Comment: @idmean: Nachdem in Gegenden, wo bairische Dialekte gesprochen werden, die Kurzform *'ner* nicht verwendet wird (*»in 'ner Kirche«* → *»in ana Kirchn«*), stufe ich sowohl *'ner* als auch *ana* als Dialektwörter ein. (Ich habe die weibliche *Kneipe* nicht verwendet, weil sie im österreichischen Alltagsvokabular nicht vorkommt und durch das sächliche *Beisl* ersetzt wird. Vergleiche dazu die österreichische und die deutsche Version eines Peter Alexander-Hits: Ö: [Das kleine Beisl](https://youtu.be/cpGMVgiiUMk), D: [Die kleine Kneipe](https://youtu.be/A10I_3e8B_I))

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Nur weil ein bestimmtes Wort in einem bestimmten Dialekt nicht vorkommt, heißt das nicht, dass es nicht sonst Teil der deutschen (Umgangs-)Sprache sein kann. Z. B. sagt man in Österreich auch nicht „Quark“. Ist damit „Quark“ jetzt auch ein Dialektwort? In vielen Schweizer Dialekten sagt man statt Butter „Anke“. Ist deshalb Butter jetzt ein Dialektwort?

Comment: @idmean: Da hast Du sicher Recht, andererseits gehört auch nicht jedes Wort, nur weil man es in Norddeutschland verwendet, zur Hochsprache. "'ner" ist jedenfalls sicher keine Hochsprache und auch keine Standardsprache. Ob es Dialekt, Umgangssprache oder sonstwas ist, will ich gar nicht beurteilen.

Comment: @bakunin  "in der Sprache, in der "inner" ein Wort ist, da existiert auch nur ein Artikel: de" Das ist wirklich eine Fehleinschätzung, das hat nichts miteinander zu tun und sind unterschiedliche Dialekte, "Inner" ist einfach nur das ausschließlich und eindeutig weibliche Äquivalent zu "im" (also mit Dativ Singular). Gleiches gilt für "anner". Mit Akkusativ ist es "inne" bzw. "anne".

Comment: @HalvarF: das war wohl unglücklich ausgedrückt. Was ich eigentlich meinte war, daß "inner" (genauso wie das von Dir angesprochene "anner" und ähliche) eben Dialekt sind (allerbestenfalls Umgangssprache) und *eben nicht* Standardsprache. "Beim" (für "bei dem" oder "im" (für "in dem") hingegen sehr wohl und darauf hat sich meine Frage bezogen. Es scheint aber so, als wäre tofros Vermutung, "wäre halt schwer auszusprechen" zutreffend.

Answer (score 1):

Verkürzungen werden im Allgemeinen gemacht, um das Sprechen zu vereinfachen und "schneller" zu machen.

Eine Verkürzung von "bei der" analog zum Maskulinum und zum Neutrum würde wohl auf etwas wie "beir" hinauslaufen. Da das allerdings keine gängige Lautkombination im Deutschen ist und relativ schwer in verständlicher Form von der Zunge geht, hat sich diese Verkürzung wohl nicht etabliert - sie wäre kontraproduktiv.

Es gibt durchaus Zusammenziehungen im Femininum (wie "inner Kneipe", siehe Kommentar von @Janka), die gängigere Lautkombinationen ergeben und sich durchgesetzt haben.

Comment: "beir" schreibt man natürlich nicht. Aber die Kombination "bei der" wird sprachlich durchaus verkürzt zu sowas wie "beia" (ähnlich wie "inner Kneipe", "aufa Walz" und "innes Haus") - was alles aber kein Schriftdeutsch ist.

Comment: @planetmaker Das kenne ich aus meiner Region überhaupt nicht. Scheint in Süddeutschland nicht üblich zu sein. Im Gegenteil, da wird das "d" von "der" eher noch verstärkt statt verschluckt.

Comment: Interessant. Ich habe gerade mal den Atlas der Alltagssprache durchstöbert, aber hierzu gibt es darin - soweit ich gesehen habe - noch keine Erhebung. Nur bezüglich der Abkürzung für ein/e gibt es einen Eintrag: https://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-5/f18a-b/

Comment: Die Aussage, dass es keine gängige Lautkombination ergibt, kann ich nicht nachvollziehen. Bei mir gehört "beir" zum normalen Wortschatz, und ich spreche es /baɪ̯ɐ/ aus, es reimt sich also mit Bayer, Meier, Rheier etc.

Comment: "Verkürzungen", haha, die werden in Antworten gemacht, um Antwortenden das Antworten zu erleichtern.

Answer (score -5):

> Dies ist allerdings nur für Maskulina und Neutra der Fall, nicht jedoch für Feminina

Das ist nicht korrekt. *Zur* ist ein sehr häufiges Wort, allein über 1200 mal im BGB der BRD.

https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bgb/BJNR001950896.html

Falls dennoch Zweifel bestehen von wegen die Frage sei "in Bezug auf *die deutsche Sprache formuliert", verweise ich gesondert auf StGB: Volksverhetzung.

> Wer […] zu einer vorbezeichneten Gruppe oder zu einem Teil der Bevölkerung zum Hass aufstachelt, zu Gewalt- oder Willkürmaßnahmen auffordert […]

Man könnte ja meinen, *zur* sei falsch. Gibt sicherlich einen Rechtsschreibparagraphen der das regelt.

Also gehen wir ohne Überleitung zur Tatsachenbetrachtung. Denn bei anderen Praepositionen wird es in der Tat schwieriger, bleibt jedoch unklar was "es" ist. Phonologie? Etymologie? Sprachökonomie?

Als erster Vergleichswert sei auf T-Glottalization im Cockney-English verwiesen, bspw. *li'l* anstatt *little*, häufiger auch *liddel*.

Etwas anders verhält es sich in der Umgangssprache mit *bei'r Frau*. Da *-r* ohnehin vokalisiert, vgl. *Bayern* /ˈb̥ai̯.ɐn/, und so mit Iotazismus in den Hochvokal assimiliert, entfällt der Kontrast zwischen Schwa Vorderzungenvokal und Tiefschwa zu gunsten eines Diphtongs über den betonten Zentralvokal, vorrausgesetzt das d wird elidiert. Eine Verallgemeinerung kann man daraus nicht schließen, sondern muss diese erstmal vorausagesetzt werden wegen der Fragestellung bzgl. *im* / *in dem*. Dies kann mit mundartlich *inna* soweit bestätigt werden.

> ick war inne Schule ***

> ick fahr inne Kofhalle

Man könnte lediglich vermuten, dass meinetwegen *#i'r* /ɪ.ɐ/ wäre zu erwarten. Im Vergleich zu *ihr* /iːɐ̯/, was verwandt mit 2.pl *euch*, engl. *you, your*, bzw. 3.sg *her* in andere Richtung schlägt, steht ferner ein betont diphtongiertes *ein*, *komm herein*, was wiederum mit monophtongen im Niederdeutschen kolidiert, bspw. *eens* "1". Die unbetonte Form *in* /ʔɪn/ hält dem eingangs angeführten Vergleich mit /-ai̯.ɐ/ offenbar nicht recht stand.

Denkbar wäre jedenfalls, dass die Lösung des Problems in der Entstehung der bestimmten Artikel im West-Germanischen und dem Unterschied zum unbestimmten liegt. Wie oben gezeigt, können diese sogar innerhalb eines verklausulierten Satzes wechseln (bestimmt "zum Hass" neben unbestimmt "zu Gewalt- und Willkürmaßnahmen”).

Weitere Überlegung spar ich mir erstmal und verweise die Frage zurück an' Fragesteller mit dem Hinweis, dass nicht genügend Vorarbeit geleistet wurde.

Comment: Was genau ist bei "zur [...] nicht korrekt"? Daß ich es ausdrücklich als im Gegensatz zu "bei" und "in" befindlich erwähnt habe?